# & character not retained in text_field_tag value from URL param

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having an issue where the & character is missing from form text field when pulled from the URL parameter.  Other characters seem fine, such as quotes ".

```
<%= text_field_tag "v0", params["v0"] %>
```

When I use 'r&r' it shows as 'r%26r' in the URL, but ends up as 'rr' in the text field.

```
v0=r%26r
```

I have tried using URI.unescape and it did the same placing 'rr' in the text field.

```
<%= text_field_tag "v0", URI.unescape(params["v0"]) %>
```

I'm aware this doesn't account for nil right now.  I just need to retain that & character in the text field.

Comment: That's odd, `<%= text_field_tag "v0", params["v0"] %>` alone should work. Can you show the complete form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails will automatically decode GET and POST values for you. Remove URI.unescape and your code should work.

RoR docs (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#parameters) mention this:

> The actual URL in this example will be encoded as "/clients?ids%5b%5d=1&ids%5b%5d=2&ids%5b%5d=3" as the "[" and "]" characters are not allowed in URLs. Most of the time you don't have to worry about this because the browser will encode it for you, and **Rails will decode it automatically**, but if you ever find yourself having to send those requests to the server manually you should keep this in mind.